# MySQL full text issue - How to match two columns in the same query?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I'm trying to run a simple query like this:

```
SELECT *, 
MATCH(`col1`,`col2`) 
AGAINST ('some text') AS score
FROM `mytable` ORDER BY score DESC
```

This always gives the error:

```
#1191 - Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list
```

But if I split the columns and do two queries like this:

```
SELECT *, 
MATCH(`col1`) 
AGAINST ('some text') AS score
FROM `mytable` ORDER BY score DESC
```

and:

```
SELECT *, 
MATCH(`col2`) 
AGAINST ('some text') AS score
FROM `mytable` ORDER BY score DESC
```

Then that works. Why can't I match against both columns at the same time? I see an example on the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html) doing almost exactly the same thing like this:

```
mysql> SELECT id, body, MATCH (title,body) AGAINST
    -> ('Security implications of running MySQL as root') AS score
    -> FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body) AGAINST
    -> ('Security implications of running MySQL as root');
```

Comment: Check this on the manual. `FULLTEXT (title,body)` in `CREATE TABLE articles`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#1191 - Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list`

You need to have FULLTEXT index on both the columns together.
 `FULLTEXT (col1,col2)`

Comment: Sometimes what you need is a fresh look. Happens with me all the time :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to have an index that matches your queried fields. From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-restrictions.html):

> The MATCH() column list must match exactly the column list in some FULLTEXT index definition for the table,